# Jquery setInterval with dynamic array

Tags: jquery, arrays, setinterval

this is my first post here, so i'm not exactly sure about my posting title or the rest of this post being to broad or vague.

This is my number 1 site for solving my problems. but now i'm stuck. i managed to put together a jquery image slide show(not a plugin) from some code i found on this site. i made some modifications here and there and add a couple of input fields. 
here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8BRzr/48/ with my problem commented.

i believe my problem lies in the setInterval part of the jquery code

```
$(function(){
    $('#addimage').click(function(){
    if($( "#addimagefield" ).val().trim().length !='' && $( "#image1" ).val().trim().length ==''){
        $( "#image1" ).val( $("#addimagefield").val().trim() );
        $( "#addimagefield" ).val( '' );
    } if($( "#addimagefield" ).val().trim().length !='' && $( "#image2" ).val().trim().length ==''){
        $( "#image2" ).val( $("#addimagefield").val().trim() );
        $( "#addimagefield" ).val( '' );
    } if($( "#addimagefield" ).val().trim().length !='' && $( "#image3" ).val().trim().length ==''){
        $( "#image3" ).val( $("#addimagefield").val().trim() );
        $( "#addimagefield" ).val( '' );
    } if($( "#addimagefield" ).val().trim().length !='' && $( "#image4" ).val().trim().length ==''){
        $( "#image4" ).val( $("#addimagefield").val().trim() );
        $( "#addimagefield" ).val( '' );
    } if($( "#addimagefield" ).val().trim().length !='' && $( "#image5" ).val().trim().length ==''){
        $( "#image5" ).val( $("#addimagefield").val().trim() );
        $( "#addimagefield" ).val( '' );
    }
    image1 = $('#image1').val();
    image2 = $('#image2').val();
    image3 = $('#image3').val();
    image4 = $('#image4').val();
    image5 = $('#image5').val();

var arr = [ image1,image2,image3,image4,image5 ];
var images = $.grep( arr, function( n, i ) {
  return n != '';
});
var cur_image = 0;
function changeBackground() {
    cur_image++;
    if ( cur_image >= images.length )
        cur_image = 0;

    // change images
    $( '.featuredImages' ).css({
        backgroundImage: 'url(' + images[ cur_image ] + ')'
    });
    $( '.featuredImages .slide' ).fadeIn( 2000, function(){
        $( this ).css({
            backgroundImage: 'url(' + images[ cur_image ] + ')'
        }).show();
    } );

};
setInterval( changeBackground, 6000 );
});
});
```

upon searching i came across the settimeout() function this seems like what i need but i have no clue where/how to implement it.

Any and all help is appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have declared the `changeBackground` function inside the event handler for the click, so it's only available inside that scope. When you try to use it outside, it's undefined.

Move the function out of the event handler, and also declare the `image` and `cur_image` variables outside that scope, as the function uses them:

http://jsfiddle.net/8BRzr/49/

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly how i wanted it to work now i just got to wait 2 minutes to check as answered